# How to get specific ID from multi ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my case, I want to make plus or minus button with add or minus to count number into text box. I can do it. But I've got the error. There have multi row with same design but different ID (I mean working with auto increment ID). When I click on plus button of top or middle row but it doesn't work on it's own row. It's always work on the last row.

Here is my Screenshot
[image]

Here is my HTML in JQuery Code. When Click on Add button at right top corner, this code work. It's doesn't the problem.

```
<input id="qty1" type="text" class="form-control dateadd" style="border-     radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0">
```

Here is my processing JQuery codes.

```
var test;
$('.dateadd').each(function() {
    var test =  this.id;
    console.log("ID is",test, "Hello, world!");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.plus').click( function() {
        var counter = $(test).val();
        counter++ ;
        $(test).val(counter);
    });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.minus').click( function() {
        var counter = $(test).val();
        counter-- ;
        $(test).val(counter);
    });
});
```

Here is my Row HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right:0;">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-default plus" type="button" style="background-color:#7ec1cb;color:#fff;border-radius:0px;">＋</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default minus" style="color:#7ec1cb;border-radius:0px;">－</a>    
      </span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control qty" style="border-radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my Row Add Jquery + HTML Code

```
  var perDayHtml = '<div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right:0;">'+
                                        '<div class="input-group">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-btn">'+
                                                '<a class="btn btn-default plus" type="button" style="background-color:#7ec1cb;color:#fff;border-radius:0px;">＋</a>'+
                                                '<a class="btn btn-default minus" style="color:#7ec1cb;border-radius:0px;">－</a>'+
                                            '</span>'+
                                            '<input id="qty1" type="text"   class="form-control dateadd" style="border-radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0">'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'

 $("#optionBox").on('click', '.addPerDay', function(){
     $('.remove').prop('disabled', false);
    if (rowNo<maxi && rowNo<minusmaxi) {

        rowNo++;
        plan++;

        $(".perDay:last").after(perDayHtml.replace(/qty1/g,"qty" + rowNo));
```

Comment: Add your HTML code plz.

Comment: your html is contradictory - one says the input class is qty, the other says it is dateadd - which one its it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you've `plus/minus` button in same div with the `dateadd` input so you could just go up to the parent `div` then find the `dateadd` input :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.plus', function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('div');
        var counter = parseInt(parent.find('.qty').val());
        counter++ ;
        parent.find('.qty').val(counter);
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.minus', function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('div');
        var counter = parseInt(parent.find('.qty').val());
        counter-- ;
        parent.find('.qty').val(counter);
    });
});
```

**NOTE 1:** NO need for multiple `ready` function.

**NOTE 2:** You should use event delegation `.on()` instead of `.click()` since your code is added dynamically to the DOM.

**NOTE 3:** Check in `minus` click event if the `qte` is greater than 0 before decreasing the counter :

```
counter>0?counter--:counter;
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.plus', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var counter = parseInt(parent.find('.qty').val());
    counter++ ;
    parent.find('.qty').val(counter);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.minus', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div');
    var counter = parseInt(parent.find('.qty').val());
    counter>0?counter--:counter;
    parent.find('.qty').val(counter);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-default plus" type="button" style="background-color:#7ec1cb;color:#fff;border-radius:0px;">＋</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default minus" style="color:#7ec1cb;border-radius:0px;">－</a>    
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control qty" style="border-radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0"> 
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-default plus" type="button" style="background-color:#7ec1cb;color:#fff;border-radius:0px;">＋</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default minus" style="color:#7ec1cb;border-radius:0px;">－</a>    
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control qty" style="border-radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0"> 
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-default plus" type="button" style="background-color:#7ec1cb;color:#fff;border-radius:0px;">＋</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default minus" style="color:#7ec1cb;border-radius:0px;">－</a>    
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control qty" style="border-radius:0px;" name="count_date[]" value="0"> 
</div>
```

Comment: +1 although now OP has added html structure, it is not clear whether he wants quantity or date add to be updated

Comment: I've updated my answer.. thanks for your intervention @Pete.

Comment: Bro. It's work at the last row to increase and decrease correctly But the middle rows have increase the number + row count. Example: i have 3 rows. I increase in last row it's working perfect. When i increase in 2nd row, It increase 2+ And when i increase in 1st row, it increase 3+. If i have 5 rows the 1st row increase +5. If i have 10 row the 1st row increase +10. What should i do bro? It's so close to correct. Please advice me.

Comment: Hi bro, make sure that you aren't attaching the events `plus/minus` clicks inside another event or inside a loop. it looks like the event is reattached every time you click.. also make sure that you don't have nested divs and every div is separated of others.

Comment: Yes bro, I tested with as your code. I think when i add that rows by using Jquery. It's conflict. When i made with manually added rows, It's work. But in my work, It's need to create rows by using jquery on button click.

As my screenshot, When I click on Add button at right top corner then the same row is added. That's the start of code conflict. :(

Comment: NO worries you could post new question with relevant code and i'll try my best to solve this conflict with you :)